# SQLException deleting row from JTable and database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

I want to delete selcetd row in a `JTable` from both the table itself and the database.

That is my code:

```
Object number =  jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow-1, 0);
                String sql = "delete  from orders where number ="+number;
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                rs = null;
                rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

When the `excuteQuery()` runs I get the following exception:

```
(java.sql.SQLException) java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to use executeUpdate method instead of executeQuery method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an `Abnormal Exception`.

You need to call `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`. You cannot update database by calling `executeQuery` method. To update something in database (insert, update, delete) you need to call `executeUpdate` method and it will **not** return the `ResultSet` and instead return you an `int` value.

`int result = st.executeUpdate(sql);`

[More Info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29)